Username spaces yes or no?
From the activation letter -
Please make sure that your username does not have any spaces in it.
Several special characters are allowed, including space, period (.), hyphen (-), apostrophe ('), underscore (_), and the @ sign.

Is this for a username on civicrm.org? It does have a limitation for spaces, but in general with a drupal site you can have spaces.

Welcome to StackExchange! Could you provide a bit more detail? In particular which site are you referring to? That would help people to answer your question.
